# Insertion and Extraction operators C++ Alternating Input output

Tags: c++, operators, insertion

The code below is a code that I am trying to get output a statement, the statement will ask for user input then move to the next output requesting another user input.

I have narrowed the code down to the part that i have questions on, currently the code will display like this:

---

Enter the First name: 
Enter the middle name:
Enter the last name:
*(then the user can input)*
Employee type ((S)alaried / (H)ourly:
PayRate \t\t\t    : 
Enter the hours worked for this week:

---

However what I need to have happen is for it to ask for the input then allow the user to input before display the next outputted statement, like:

Enter the First name: (user input)
Enter the middle name: (user input) 
etc...

I have searched online, but I am not finding anything that fits this need. I am all for learning, any help is appreciated.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, Person& PerObj) {


    output << "Enter the first name : " << endl;
    output << "Enter the middle name: " << endl;
    output << "Enter the last name  : " << endl;
    return output;
}
istream& operator>> (istream& input, Person& PerObj) {

    input >> PerObj.FirstName;
    input >> PerObj.MiddleName;
    input >> PerObj.LastName;

    return input;
}


// Employee -------------
ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, Employee& EmpObj) {

    Person PersonObj;
    cout << PersonObj;
    output << "Employee type ((S)alaried / (H)ourly: " << endl;
    output << "PayRate \t\t\t    : " << endl;
    output << "Enter the hours worked for this week: " << endl;


    return output;
}
istream& operator>> (istream& input, Employee& EmpObj) {

    return input;
}


Person::Person() {


}

Employee::Employee() {


}


void main()
{
    Employee e;

    cout << endl << e;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    Student s;

    cout << endl << s;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Wrong approach. Insertion operator is for displaying the object, not for prompting the user. Simply don't use insertion and extraction operators in this case.

Comment: Thank you, so if the requirement of the this code was to use the >> Operator to gather the users input for each of those items, what would be a more recommended approach?